# Google Play services - Use XP points/ Acheivements to trigger list of activities

Tags: android, google-play-services

The documentation for this seems to be very confusing to me. But basically is there a way I can track the points/achievements unlocked in Google play services (or even display them somewhere individually?), so that in turn I can display in a listview "unlocked" items the user can use?

I just need to know if their is an initial call method that can help me with this (I'm a beginner in android) thanks